# shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException: An exception while trying read from storage container in azure blob storage

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage, databricks

when I try to run this line of code in databricks:

```
date_config = spark.read.option("header", True).option("inferSchema", True).csv(f"{DBX_SAMPLE_MNT}/dateconfig/date_config.csv")
```

I got this error:

shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException: hadoop_azure_shaded.com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.

I tried these solutions I found here like:

- generate new SAS key token under the storage account level and also in storage container level, but nothing worked.
- Azure Portal -> Storage Account -> Networking -> Check Allow Access From (All Networks / Selected Networks) doesn't work.
- Check account Key...they were correct.
- tried to on/off VPN and also check my PC's time...yet the error still persist.

What may be other possible solutions that I need to try? P.S. those SAS key tokens were working then suddenly the error came. Even though SAS tokens not yet expired.

Comment: how do you set SAS token or account key?

Comment: In the Permissions field, selected Read, Write, Delete, List, and Create.
Set the start and expiry date a year from when I create it.
In the Allowed IP addresses field.
Click Generate SAS token

Comment: I meant how you set it on Spark side. Also what IPs have you entered

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above scenario, and I got same error, when I have given wrong SAS. The remaining settings of SAS are same.

[image]

You can see it mounted successfully but got the same error when I am trying to read the file.

Recheck the SAS that you are getting and if the error still persists, then its better to raise a [Support ticket](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request) for deeper investigation.